# How to import a DataFrame of mixed type and organize into columns in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am importing a .txt file via read_table and get a DataFrame similar to

```
d = ['89278 5857', '1.000e-02', '1.591184e-02', '2.100053e-02', '89300 5857', '4.038443e-01', '4.037924e-01', '4.037336e-01']
df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)
```

and would like to reorganize it into

```
r = {'89278 5857': [1.000e-02, 1.591184e-02, 2.100053e-02], '89300 5857': [4.038443e-01, 4.037924e-01, 4.037336e-01]}
rf = pd.DataFrame(data = r)
```

The .txt file is typically 50k+ rows with an unknown number of '89278 5857' type values.
Thanks!

Comment: Just a few questions. Is there anything specific about `"89300 5857"`, ... . Does it start with `89XXX XXXX` or is it more general? Are the number of values for each `89XXX XXXX` constant?

Comment: The form is XXXXX XXXX or XXXXXX XXXX (they don't necessarily have to start with 89). The number of values will be equal in each column.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby

data, cur_group = {}, None
for v, g in groupby(df[0], lambda k: " " in k):
    if v:
        cur_group = []
        data[next(g)] = cur_group
    else:
        cur_group.extend(g)

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
     89278 5857    89300 5857
0     1.000e-02  4.038443e-01
1  1.591184e-02  4.037924e-01
2  2.100053e-02  4.037336e-01
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming what delineates the start of the next group is a space, here what I would:

```py
df.assign(
    key=lambda df: numpy.where(
        df['value'].str.contains(' '),  # what defines each group
        df['value'],
        numpy.nan
    ),
).fillna(
    method='ffill'  # copy the group label down until the next group starts
).loc[
    lambda df: df['value'] != df['key']  # remove the rows that kicked off each group
].assign(
    idx=lambda df: df.groupby('key').cumcount()  # get a row number for each group
).pivot(  
    index='idx',  # pivot into the wide format
    columns='key',
    values='value'
).astype(float)  # turn values into numbers instead of strings
```

And I get:

```
key  89278 5857  89300 5857
idx                        
0      0.010000    0.403844
1      0.015912    0.403792
2      0.021001    0.403734
```

Comment: I am getting several errors with this relating to 'value'. Any idea why this might be?

Comment: @rypo06 Oh I added that as the name of the column in your example dataframe. Replace it with whatever your column is actually called

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately this just gives me an empty dataframe.

Comment: Are you assigning the output?

Comment: I did. I set 'dam = df.assign...' and then call dam. The code runs, my df has a single column (values) with 23,000 values but dam remains empty.